# Create a copy of a worksheet and name it based on a list

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I'm trying to create a copy of a worksheet in a workbook for each entry in a range, then rename the worksheet based on the value of the current cell in that range. It was working before, but now it doesn't name the new sheets. If I make blank worksheets, it will name them, however if I copy the worksheet it won't name the worksheet properly. I am also trying to set the value of C1 on each sheet to the value that is from the range. Below is my code:

```
    Sub CreateSEMSheets()
    On Error GoTo GetOut


    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

    Set MyRange = Sheets("Strategic End Market Data").Range("SEMListGenerated")

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
    If MyCell.Value = "" Then GoTo GetOut

        Sheets("StrategicMktPlan").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "SMP - " & MyCell.Value
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("C1").Value = MyCell.Value
    Next MyCell

GetOut:

End Sub
```

Please help!!! Thanks in advance.

**Edit: I figured out why it's not working - there was a hidden sheet that was the last sheet in the workbook and it was renaming that over and over. Any idea how to prevent this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Copy() method of Worksheet object the newly created worksheet is the *active* one:

```
For Each MyCell In MyRange
    If MyCell.Value = "" Then GoTo GetOut

    Sheets("StrategicMktPlan").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    With ActiveSheet
        .Name = "SMP - " & MyCell.Value
        .Range("C1").Value = MyCell.Value
     End With
Next MyCell
```

Comment: I tried implementing this but for some reason it still stops early - it creates one sheet, renames it and copies the value into C1, but after that it copies the the original sheet and quits even though there are still several items left in the list. There aren't any hidden sheets or anything like that to hang it up so I'm at wits end...

Comment: I figured it out - the value of the cell was too long and it was throwing an error. I resized the cells and it works like a charm. Thanks!!

Comment: You are welcome. You may then want to accept my answer and give people reading this thread this is the working answer to your question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Per your edit, you could use this:

```
Sub VisibleSheetsCount()
'UpdatebyKutoolsforExcel20150909
' https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3187-excel-count-visible-sheets.html
    Dim xSht As Variant
    Dim I As Long
    For Each xSht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If xSht.Visible Then I = I + 1
    Next
    MsgBox I & " sheets are visible", , "Kutools for Excel"
End Sub
```

Then do `.Copy(After:=Sheets(I))` I think would work.